# Selenium getText() versus BeautifulSoup get_text()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

Is there one of these better than the other? i.e faster, better parsing, etc.

I am already using Selenium to write my scraping module.

Going with BeautifulSoup means I would have to import it, not sure if its worth it.

Comment: There usually isn't a choice.  BeautifulSoup reads static HTML.  Selenium reads the live DOM from a running instance of Chrome.  If you can get what you need using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`, that is BY FAR the better choice.  If you need Javascript to be interpreted, then that won't work, and you must use Selenium and run a Chrome instance..